# svg + inkscape + unwanted cropping

Tags: svg, inkscape

Given the following test.svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="tiny" 
  height="5cm" version="1.2" 
  viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" 
  width="5cm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs />
  <rect fill="blue" height="1" width="1" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

using the command

```
inkscape -D -z --file=test.svg --export-pdf=text.pdf --export-latex
```

I get a pdf of 25mm x 25mm. The proportions are correct (I use only half the width and half the height), my question is how do avoid an automatic crop of the picture. I need a PDF of 50mm x 50mm, with only the left upper square filled.

In the `inkscape` documentation for the option `-D` (that I use) there is the comment *without margins or cropping* that is exactly what I need. The result is as described above, cropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man inkscape` shows the following explanation for `-D`:

> In SVG, PNG, PDF, PS, and EPS export, exported area is the drawing (not page), i.e. the bounding box of all objects of the document...

That is what you describe as cropping. For `-C` it says:

> In SVG, PNG, PDF, PS, and EPS export, exported area is the page. This is the default for SVG, PNG, PDF, and PS, so you don't need to specify this...

So, simply leave off the `-D` option.

Comment: simpler is better, thank you. now I have only a vertical inversion, but I'm not surprised

Comment: I suspect that the vertical inversion can be fixed by removing the - signs from the viewbox.